# express-x-hub with typescript fail to build

Tags: typescript, express

```
import xhub from 'express-x-hub';

router

    .post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
        if (!req.isXHubValid()) {
            console.log('Warning - request header X-Hub-Signature not present or invalid');
            res.sendStatus(401);
            return;
        }
        res.sendStatus(200)
    })
```

Error:

`Property 'isXHubValid' does not exist on type 'Request<{}, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>`

How can I make the compiler recognize this method?